# Unable to Update Angle of a RotateTransform for an Image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, data-binding, rotatetransform

I am attempting to update the Rotation Angle of an image in a custom WPF UserControl named MarkerImage.  I have a property on MarkerImage named Heading and when that changes, I want the Angle of the image to change.  I've tried numerous methods, and they all set the initial angle correctly, but none of them are able to update the angle. Here is the XAML of the control:

Here are some of the methods I've tried:

1) Created a Dependency Property on MarkerImage named Heading.

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeadingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Heading", typeof(uint), typeof(MarkerImage), new PropertyMetadata(default(uint)));
```

Then I set the DataContext of MarkerImage to {RelativeSource Self} and Bound the Angle property of the RotateTransform to that Heading property:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Pilot2ATC_EFB.Map.MarkerImage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Pilot2ATC_EFB.Map"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" Width="35" Height="35" x:Name="ctlMarkerImage">
<Image x:Name="userImage" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="34" Width="34" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Source="/myApplication;component/Resources/arrow.png" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform" Angle="{Binding  Path=Heading,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

This correctly sets  the Angle when the Control is created and the Heading property is set.  However, as the Heading property is updated in the Set{} of the Heading property:

```
SetValue(HeadingProperty, value % 360);
```

the image angle does not change.

2)Attempted to set the Angle property directly from the property Heading Set code:

```
    _Heading = value % 360;
    rotateTransform.Angle = _Heading;
```

This again worked to set the initial Angle, but did not change the rotation of the image when Heading was updated.
3) Attempted to replace the RotateTransform with a new one each time the Heading changed:

```
    userImage.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(_Heading);
```

This also worked to set the initial Angle, but did nothing when the Heading value changed thereafter.

4) Attempted to do an animation of the Angle property when the Heading changed. (rotateTransform is the x:Name of the RotateTransform element):

```
     var rotAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(Heading, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
     rotateTransform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, rotAnimation);
```

And once again, the initial value was set correctly, but updated had no effect.

Here's the code where the Heading property is set when using the DependencyProperty.

```
    public double Heading
    {
        get  { return (double)GetValue(HeadingProperty); }  
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
                value = 360;
            SetValue(HeadingProperty, value % 360);
        }
    }
```

Of course, I confirmed that the code was executing and the heading value was changing after the initial setting, but the image was not being rotated.

I have tried 10+ other variations of these and other suggestions in  the forums, but they either threw errors, didn't set the initial value or had the same result as these 4.

It would seem that there is a definitive way to change the rotation angle of an image in a WPF UserControl dynamically from code behind or via Binding, but I am at a loss as to what that would be.  ANY help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not totally sure, but one possible problem. Is `DataContext` being set by the `Window` that's hosting your `MarkerImage`? This might brake the binding after the initial value is set. To test, try removing `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` and instead add `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={AncestorType local:MarkerImage}}"` to the root element (in your case the `Image`).

Comment: First of all, a UserControl should never explicitly set its own DataContext. Doing so beaks the usual DataContext Bindings, e.g. `Heading="{Binding Something}"` would no longer work. The Binding to the UserControl's own property should look like `Angle="{Binding Heading, RelativeSource={AncestorType=UserControl}}`, without the UpdateSourceTrigger, which has no effect in OneWay Bindings.

Comment: Then the type of the property should be `double`, not `uint`. Besides that, we can't answer your question until you show us the code where you actually try to set the Heading property. If that is a Binding, it may not work due to the reason mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions.  I added the code used to set the Heading DependencyProperty value to the question.  I also tried both of your suggestions on setting the DataContext and Binding values, along with several variations of  both.  They had the same result of the initial setting working, but updates not working.  It's as if the Angle of a RotateTransform cannot be changed....which is what prompted approach #3 to replace it instead of trying to change it.  But that didn't work either.

Comment: Well you can definitely change the angle of a rotate transform (I just tested it myself). There's not much more I an think of without a reproducible example. Side note: the logic and validation you have for `Heading` shouldn't be placed in the setter, instead it should go in [validation and/or coercion callbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-callbacks-and-validation). This is because that setter will not be called if the property is updated via binding (the WPF binding system directly calls `SetValue`).

Comment: @Keith you are correct.  I built a small app that is able to turn an arrow.  I will post that code for anyone else coming along with a similar question.  I suspect my issue is deeper in the application code.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small app that seems to work and demonstrates the changing of the Angle property of a RotateTransform.  In fact, there are many ways to do this.  This is one that uses a DependencyProperty Approach.

Here's the Application Window XAML without the Window standard content:

```
    <Grid Margin="0,0,2,1">
    <local:ImageMarker x:Name="imgMarker" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" 
                       Margin="45,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="32"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtHeading" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="174,44,0,0" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextChanged="txtHeading_TextChanged"/>

</Grid>
```

Here's the Application Window code behind:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Marker marker;
    private void txtHeading_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(marker == null)
            marker = new Marker(imgMarker);
        if (txtHeading.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            double val;
            var result = double.TryParse(txtHeading.Text, out val);
            if (result)
                marker.Heading = val;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Marker Object that will control the ImageMarker:

```
    class Marker : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private ImageMarker imageMarker;

    public Marker(ImageMarker imgMarker)
    {
        imageMarker = imgMarker;
    }


    private double _Heading;
    public double Heading
    {
        get { return _Heading; }
        set
        {
            if (value <= 0)
                value = 360;
            _Heading = value % 360;
            imageMarker.Heading = _Heading;
            //imageMarker.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(_Heading);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the commented out line in the Heading Setter.  That method of changing the angle of the image also worked...No Binding required.

Here's the ImageMarker XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestRotateTransform.ImageMarker"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestRotateTransform"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" Width="32" Height="32">
<Image Source="Resources/arrow_up.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Heading, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1,AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Image.RenderTransform>

</Image>
```

And finally, here's the ImageMarker code behind with the addition of propertychanged, coercion and validation callbacks as suggested by Keith:

```
    public partial class ImageMarker : UserControl
{
    public ImageMarker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeadingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Heading",
        typeof(double), typeof(ImageMarker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnHeadingChanged),
            new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceHeading)),new ValidateValueCallback(IsValidHeading));

    private static void OnHeadingChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        d.CoerceValue(HeadingProperty);
    }

    private static object CoerceHeading(DependencyObject d, object value)
    {
        double hdg = (double)value;
        if (hdg <= 0)
            hdg = 360;
        return hdg % 360;
    }
    private static bool IsValidHeading(object value)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public double Heading
    {
        get  { return (double)GetValue(HeadingProperty); }  // { return _Heading; }     // 
        set
        {
            SetValue(HeadingProperty, value % 360);
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks to Keith and Clemens for their suggestions.  At least I know it can be done.  Apparently, in my real project, something else is causing it to fail.

Comment: To tie this issue up with a nice bow.  I just solved the problem in the program I'm working on.  There was a thread issue that was being raised after the initial loading of the marker when setting the DependencyProperty.  I added the appropriate "INVOKE" code around it and all is working.